# How would I create a JFreeChart scatterplot best fit line

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have an arraylist of points I want to include in a JFreeChart scatterplot. That works fine, but I now want a best fit line on it. After some searching, JFreeChart doesn't support such calculations directly, so what I want to do is calculate it myself and then stick a line into the chart manually. How do I get a line in a scatterplot?

```
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Data");
        for (Point p : points) {
           series.add(p.getX(), p.getY());
        }
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(chartName, "Mass", parameter, dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, true);
        return chart;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the built-in [`Regression`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/Regression.html) method [`getOLSRegression()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/Regression.html#getOLSRegression-double:A:A-), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61398612/230513), or a statistical library such as [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) to determine the slope and intercept of such a line using simple regression. Add your original data to a scatter plot, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594748/making-a-scatter-plot-using-2d-array-and-jfreechart/6598479#6598479). Add an [`XYLineAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYLineAnnotation.html) representing the endpoints of your line, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604211/jfreechart-draw-arc-on-chart/6620017#6620017).

[image]