# Get equation of line - JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

Has anyone used JFreeChart and knows if it is possible to get the equation of a line - which could either be a straight or curved line. I have looked through the API but could not see anything at first glance.

Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=110122).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I create a JFreeChart scatterplot best fit line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652319/how-would-i-create-a-jfreechart-scatterplot-best-fit-line)

Answer (score 0):

JFreeChart does not have support for this. I used this library in a personal project a few months ago and I spent quite some time in the API and on the forums. There was nothing there about generating such equations.

You can probably use the (x; y) value pairs to generate such an equation. For straight lines, it should be very easy.