# TimeSeriesChart: value at a certain timestamp

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, timeserieschart

I am using a TimeSeriesChart (jfreechart) to represent data with a chart that shows 24h. Each point of the curve consists of a double value (y axis) and a timestamp including milliseconds (x axis). If make sure that I have at least a value at 00:00:00 and at 23:59:59 - how many points there are inbetween depends on the data.

JFreeChart connects the points which are provided automatically to a curve so I was wondering if it's possible to ask the chart what a curves value is at a certain time, e.g.

```
assume I have a series with 4 points:

1.1.2012 00:00:00.000 - value = 0
1.1.2012 01:00:00.000 - value = 60
1.1.2012 23:00:00.000 - value = 600
```

and I let JFreeChart connect these points - is there any way to ask JFreeChart for the value at e.g. 22:30:00 even though I didn't provide a data point for this time?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because the points are connected with straight lines, you can use [*linear interpolation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation), as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6659201/230513). For polynomial regression, consider [`LUDecompositionImpl`](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/linear/LUDecompositionImpl.html).

Comment: Revised in 1.0.14, the built-in `Regression`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10094620/230513).