# Points on a line in jfreechart

Tags: charts, jfreechart, linechart

How to get all the points (x,y) lying on the line connecting two data-points in a chart in jfreechart ?.

In a chart, as we point to the end-points of the line, it shows the x & y coordinates. Can't we get the coordinates at any point on the line (via code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have two points, use the formulae of a [*linear equation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Forms_for_2D_linear_equations) to obtain the slope and intercept of the line. Once you have the equation, you can evaluate it at any point.

Addendum: The [`org.jfree.data.statistics.Regression`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/Regression.html) class offers some built-in support for regression analysis.

Comment: For more than two points, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6659201/230513) on regression.

Comment: yes, that's an option but doesn't jfreechat provide something for this type of requirement?