# Creating a polynomial graph using JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

How do you create a polynomial graph from a set of co-ordinate points?

And once you've done that, how would you generate an equation for it?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and [help] on how to ask a proper question.  You will get better results that way.

Comment: thnx 4 the welcome :)

Comment: i cannot find a str8 answer to my query,...the possible duplicate is not what i'm after. How do you create a curve of best fit and how would you generate an equation for it?

Comment: You'll need regression analysis, suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10086306/230513).