# JFreeChart: Increase Size of Data Point

Tags: jfreechart

This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879362/increase-size-of-dot-in-graph), but unfortunately the pointers provided in the answers are not working (the JFreeChart Forum is down).

My question is: Using the JFreeChart library, how can I increase the size of a data point in a time series scatter plot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the methods of [`ShapeUtilities`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/util/ShapeUtilities.html), some of which have a parameter that affect size. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665354/changing-the-shapes-of-points-in-scatter-plot/6669529#6669529). See also [`DefaultDrawingSupplier`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/DefaultDrawingSupplier.html) for details of how [`createStandardSeriesShapes()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/plot/DefaultDrawingSupplier.html#line.279) works.