# How to change marker size in XYPlot of jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

In the selected answer to this question I would like to change the marker size, how can i do that?

[Setting Range for X,Y Axis-JfreeChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231824/setting-range-for-x-y-axis-jfreechart)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by `XYItemRenderer.setSeriesShape`. Please refer to how [`DefaultDrawingSupplier .createStandardSeriesShapes()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/plot/DefaultDrawingSupplier.html#line.279) works.

```
    XYItemRenderer renderer = xyPlot.getRenderer();
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.blue);
    double size = 20.0;
    double delta = size / 2.0;
    Shape shape1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(-delta, -delta, size, size);
    Shape shape2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(-delta, -delta, size, size);
    renderer.setSeriesShape(0, shape1);
    renderer.setSeriesShape(1, shape2);
```

Reference: [JFreeChart: Increase Size of Data Point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7116903/2086065)