# Is there a way to change the shape size in a JasperReports chart?

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I'm building a Time series based chart that graphs Time -> double value. The chart contains at least 230 points. If I use the "show lines" option the graph doesn't display any lines. If I disselect the "show shapes" the shames disappear, but there are no dots to where the data is.

How would I change the shapes in the chart to a circular point?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd override the renderer's [`getItemShape()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#getItemShape-int-int-) method or invoke [`setSeriesShape()`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#getSeriesShape-int-) as required. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665354/changing-the-shapes-of-points-in-scatter-plot/6669529#6669529). [`ShapeUtils`](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/util/ShapeUtils.html)  is handy, too. Also consider a custom `DrawingSupplier`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754801/230513).