# Using JFreeChart Scatter Plots is there a Way to Subdivide Styles for Data Sets?

Tags: jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to render a scatter plot with a couple thousand data points.  I control the appearance/style of each ScatterPlotDataset by attaching a suitable XYLineAndShapeRendererper to each data set; eg. points in data set 1 appear as circles and points in data set 2 appear as squares.  I would like the user to be able to dynamically assign a sub-style per point in each data set; eg. if the data set were books then the user might wish to color fiction blue and nonfiction red.  Is there a way to do this without defining a new data set for each sub style?

Incidentally I am carting with XYPlot but I can switch to another chart type if necessary.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider the approaches mentioned [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115314). The [first](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115314#p174197) implements `DrawingSupplier`, as shown [here](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/6dc65fcb8cca209b8cc41429fbeea1f7ea84976a/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/plot/DefaultDrawingSupplier.java#L70):

```
class DefaultDrawingSupplier implements DrawingSupplier…
```

The [second](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115314#p174424) extends `DefaultDrawingSupplier`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545725/230513), to achieve a similar effect.

```
Paint[] paintArray = {…};
plot.setDrawingSupplier(new DefaultDrawingSupplier(
    paintArray, …
    DefaultDrawingSupplier.DEFAULT_SHAPE_SEQUENCE));
```

Of course, you can always override `getItemPaint()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875534/230513).