# Change the Lines Style and colour of a JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have 3 series:

```
XYSeries s1 = new XYSeries("one");
s1.add(1,0);
s1.add(2,1);

XYSeries s2 = new XYSeries("two");
s1.add(3,0);
s1.add(4,1);

XYSeries s3 = new XYSeries("three");
s1.add(5,0);
s1.add(6,1);
```

Which i plot as a XYLineChart:

```
XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
dataset.addSeries(s1);
dataset.addSeries(s2);
dataset.addSeries(s3);

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("title", "x", "y", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, false, false);
```

and add to a panel:

```
ChartPanel cp = new ChartPanel(chart);
panel_1.add(cp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel_1.validate();
```

How do i make it so series s1 and s2 are the same colour, and s3 is different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the renderer's `setSeriesPaint()` method to specify the `series` and `paint`. Also consider using a custom `DrawingSupplier`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754801/230513). More generally, you can override the desired `get*Paint()` methods to establish any desired color scheme, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875534/230513) for `getItemFillPaint()`

[image]