# Gradient color for series in JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have a chart with up to 100 `XYseries`. At this stage, the plot use default colors for drawing the different lines. Is it possible to have a gradient effect for all the series without setting the color for each series ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom `DrawingSupplier`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754801/230513), and let your implementation of `getNextPaint()` return the next element in a `List<Color>`. Construct your list by varying hue or saturation using `Color.getHSBColor()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875534/230513).