# How to change color of percent bar in gantt chart in dynamic report?

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, dynamic-reports

I need help about to change the color of the percent bar in gantt chart . I am using dynamic report api to generate report in pdf format.

I need to **change the color of the progress bar**, it always shows as green and I want to change it.

```
 private JasperReportBuilder build(){
 JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
 TextColumnBuilder<String> uName = col.column("Name", "name", type.stringType()).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
            TextColumnBuilder<Date> uStart = col.column("Start", "start", type.dateType());
            TextColumnBuilder<Date> uEnd = col.column("End", "end", type.dateType());
            TextColumnBuilder<Double> uProgress = col.column("Progress", "progress", type.doubleType());

            GanttChartBuilder chart2 = cht.ganttChart().customizers(new ChartCustomizer())
                .setTask(uName)
                .series(
                    cht.ganttSerie()
                        .setStartDate(uStart)
                        .setEndDate(uEnd)
                        .setPercent(uProgress)
                        ).seriesColors(new Color(163,209,255)).setDataSource(createDataSourceForGanntChart(initiativeList,initiativeGroup,periodId,subPeriodId,fullPath,model))
                .setTimeAxisFormat(
                    cht.axisFormat().setLabel(objectInitiativeChart.getCategoryLabel()))
                .setTaskAxisFormat(
                    cht.axisFormat().setLabel(objectInitiativeChart.getSeriesLabel()));

                report.summary(chart2);
return report;
}

private class ChartCustomizer implements DRIChartCustomizer, Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, ReportParameters reportParameters) {

    BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) chart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
    renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.1);
    org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis domainAxis = chart.getCategoryPlot().getDomainAxis();
    domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 6.0));
    domainAxis.setCategoryMargin(-0.5d);
  }

}
```

[image: image after applying this code . i want to replace green color to another color]

Comment: I have added tag jfreechart (this is the library used) se for example this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27720187/changing-the-colors-of-gantt-renderer

Comment: Thanx for replying ,Actully i am trying to change the color of the progress bar(percent completion of any task ) which was green in my chart image . how can i change this color ?

Comment: i am using dynamic report api to generate reports . and in reports i need to implement gantt chart . but there is no proper documentation to customize a chart . so please check this link and help me that how can i do this . http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/ganttchartreport

Comment: Basically you need to search on JFreeChart, this is the object you need to play with, I have past you an answer, have fun.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `GanttRenderer` to `setCompletePaint(Color c)`, hence now you are casting to `BarRenderer`

**Full example**

Add a chart customizer to get the `JFreeChart` object. (note you are using set which is `deprecated`)

```
chart2.addCustomizer(new DRIChartCustomizer() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, ReportParameters arg) {
        //Here we got the JFreeChart object  and we can modify it as we like
        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        //Cast to GanttRenderer
        GanttRenderer renderer = (GanttRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        //Set colors as desired.
        renderer.setIncompletePaint(Color.CYAN);
        renderer.setCompletePaint(Color.MAGENTA);
    }
});
```