# How can I change the colour of specific bars in jFreeChart bar

Tags: java, swing, colors, jfreechart, bar-chart

I have coded an application which reads a column from a jTable and plots it in a Bar Chart.
It works okay, but now, I want to colour **some** bars of the chart depending on the value it reads from the length column.

Here is a normal example of my application:

[image: Example]

And now, as I explained, I want to change the colour of specific bars, for example attending to this rule:

if length is **>18** We will colour the bar **BLUE**

else if length is **<=18** We will colour the bar **RED**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate the dataset:

```
final double[][] data = new double[][] {{4.0, 3.0, -2.0, 3.0, 6.0}};
DatasetUtilities.createCategoryDataset("Length", "Day of the Month", data);
```

Iterate through each point and define its own color when creating the renderer:

```
Paint[] colors = new Paint[data.length];
for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    color[i] = data > 18 ? Color.blue : Color.red;
}
final CategoryItemRenderer renderer = new CustomRenderer(colors);
```

This article can be useful: [Different bar chart colours within a series](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartBarChartDemo3differentcolorswithinaseries.htm)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am creating my chart like this:  for (int j=0;j<31;j++){
                    data.addValue(dias[j], dato, numDias[j]);
                }   
                chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Chart",
                        "Day of the month","Length", data, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                        true,true,true);
                CategoryPlot plot=(CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
                BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();             And I cant find the way to implement what you said

Comment: Please look at the link in the answer. It has a comprehensive example.

Comment: Also consider a `DrawingSupplier`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16754801/230513).