# Getting Assigned Paint for TimeSeries

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am obviously not understanding the documentation for the `getSeriesPaint` method. I have the `TimeSeries` object and I want to get the color being used to render it. However, it seems like I am in a catch-22. I need to know the series index (`getIndex`), but to find that I need to know the series time period. However, to find the series time period, I need to know the index. I'm looking to do something like this:

```
Color color=(Color) r1.getSeriesPaint(arg0);
```

where `r1` is the `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`. What do I use for `arg0` given the `TimeSeries` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`XYLineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html) is an `XYItemRenderer`, it invokes the `AbstractRenderer` method [`getItemPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#getItemPaint-int-int-), which "Returns the paint used to color data items as they are drawn." Note that "The default implementation passes control to the `lookupSeriesPaint()` method." Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513), the following fragment obtains the dataset and renderer from the chart. It then enumerates the series paints—shades of red and blue seen in the image:

```
JFreeChart chart = chartPanel.getChart();
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
TimeSeriesCollection tsc = (TimeSeriesCollection) plot.getDataset();
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
for (int i = 0; i < tsc.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(renderer.lookupSeriesPaint(i));
}
```

Console:

```
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=85,b=85]
java.awt.Color[r=85,g=85,b=255]
```

[image]

Alternatively, consider a custom `DrawingSupplier`, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754801/230513).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess what you are saying is that I cannot obtain the color given a specific TimeSeries object. I'll look into DrawingSupplier.

Comment: Right; the model doesn't know about color, but the view (panel > chart > plot > renderer) does. A `DrawingSupplier` gives your application _a priori_ knowledge of the colors.