# JFreeChart Get Legend Graphic

Tags: java, jfreechart

In my application, I am showing data in a table as well as through a Dual Axis Bar/Line JFreeChart. To save some space (as the charts are being saved as PNG and put on PDF with iText PDF), I wanted to take the Graphics from the Legend, use them in the tabular view, and remove the legend.

Is there a way to grab the icons that lie with the legend item? I have found the `LegendGraphic` class, which seemed like would be the method to retrieve the icon from the `LegendItem`, but have not found anything in the documentation for `LegendItem` that would indicate it does.

It would be preferable if they were returned in an object that could easily be used to create a `com.itextpdf.text.Image`, such as `byte[]` or `java.awt.Image`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a series' [`LegendItem`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/LegendItem.html) using the chart renderer's `getLegendItem()` method. You can change a series' `Shape` using the methods of [`ShapeUtilities`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/util/ShapeUtilities.html), as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665354/changing-the-shapes-of-points-in-scatter-plot/6669529#6669529). See also [`DefaultDrawingSupplier`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/DefaultDrawingSupplier.html) for details of how [`createStandardSeriesShapes()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/plot/DefaultDrawingSupplier.html#line.279) works.

Addendum: Note that the renderer's `getLegendItem()` method works even if you create the chart with no legend or later use `chart.removeLegend()`. Once you have the `LegendItem`, you can use it's attributes as required.

```
System.out.println(renderer.getLegendItem(0, 0).getShape());
System.out.println(renderer.getLegendItem(0, 0).getFillPaint());
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples. This will get me to a point I can use the Graphics2D to draw out some shapes and such. I was hoping that there was something in the API that would prevent me from having to rebuild the legend icons, but this will work nonetheless. Thanks again.

Comment: The temporary nature of `LegendItem` lets the legend stay in sync with the renderer. You can implement `RendererChangeListener` and have your table register with the renderer.