# How to display legend for Pie Chart in columns?

Tags: java, render, jfreechart, legend

I have a PieChart with many sections, legend for this PieChart renders as one row. How to render legend as two columns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method `getLegendItem()`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12222818/230513), provides all the information needed to render a legend item in any `Container` you choose. `GridLayout(0, 2)` will arrange them in two columns for any  number of rows. To suppress the existing legend, set `legend` to `false` when you call your chart factory; the items will still be available, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8302953/230513).

Addendum: Based on [`PieChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html), this fragment uses the `getLegendItems().iterator` and a variation of this [`ColorIcon`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

[image: legend image]

```
public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
    panel.add(new ChartPanel(chart));
    panel.add(createLegendPanel((PiePlot) chart.getPlot()));
    return panel;
}

private static JPanel createLegendPanel(PiePlot plot) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5));
    Iterator iterator = plot.getLegendItems().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        LegendItem item = (LegendItem) iterator.next();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(item.getLabel());
        label.setIcon(new ColorIcon(8, item.getFillPaint()));
        panel.add(label);
    }
    return panel;
}
```

Comment: Also consider a `PlotChangeListener` to update the legend panel.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this forum thread on [*Legend Alignment*](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13694&p=175283), also in the ([web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20121209023729/http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13694)).

Seems like something you are looking for. If not, please post some more information or screenshots of what you have and what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for old versions of jfreechart... But at least it shows how one could create another multi column legend class for newer versions of jfc. :) +1

Comment: @brimborium oh, I saw that the thread is some years old, but I didn't actually check the code. still a push in the right direction i guess

Comment: @moeTi: Same here, but the link is dead. Can you find the original?

Comment: @trashgod found it in wayback machine and updated the original post

Comment: @moeTi: Thanks! I supplemented your web archive link with a link to the original forum thread.