# overlapping lables in JFreeChart pie charts

Tags: graph, jfreechart

i'm using JFreeChart to plot some data in to a pie chart. when the amount of data is getting high 
the labels of the graph is overlapping as shown below?

[image]

can any one suggest me to avoid this issue and show the labels clearly??

--
Regards Rangana

Comment: You could display the values in an adjacent component, as shown [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13309587/230513

Answer (score 2):

You could use a smaller font:

```
PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
int fontSize = 10; // Adjust the size here
plot.setLabelFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to reduce this problem by showing the pie chart as a 2d pie chart rather than a 3d one. it gave me a final result like the one similar to the https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309587/230513 suggested by @trashgod

i think i will be able add more color to the solution by implementing the suggestion done by @obourgain

Thanks guys!