# How can I get the legend of a JFreeChart plot and add it to a JPanel

Tags: jfreechart

I have multiple `JFreeChart` plots in chart panels. I want to show the legend separately as a different component, as all the plots use the same legend. The way I can see this happening is to grab the legend as some form of `JComponent` and add it to the panel along with the chart panels?

Any suggestions?

Comment: sorry about the title, i cant change it, should read ..."and add"

Comment: You may be able to use the approach shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13309587/230513).