# Add listener to Legend

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am using `XYPlot` class from **jfreechart** library. I have got two `XYSeries` and there are legend of them in the bottom of the **ChartPanel**. Now I want to process mouse click events on that legend. Is it possible to add listener to the legend? If it is not how can I get the coordinates of legend (with coordinates I can add listener to `ChartPanel`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309587/230513), you can create your own component in which to render legend items. The example decorates each `JLabel` with a [`ColorIcon`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), which is also suitable for a `JButton`.