# Jfree chart legend- displaying names and values in own columns instead of both in one column

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have a pie chart with legend on the right side. Legend's labels consist of name and value. Currently I format legend labels as "{0} {1}". What I need actually, that values don't just follow the names, but will be placed in own column. It is like a table layout, where names are in first column and values in second one.

I checked documentation but couldn't figure out.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13307500/230513).

Comment: @trashgod thanks for response, but I am looking to display one legened item in 2 columns like "name - value", name in one column and value in other column. I am not looking to display two legend items in one row.

Comment: Seems possible; where are you stuck?

Comment: I stuck at creating layout for each legend items. I am trying to show legend with table structure, percentages right aligned and labels left aligned. Is there a way I could provide a table layout for each legend item? Gridlayout works for arranging the legend items, but I am looking how to arrange inside the legenditem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507357/jfree-chart-how-to-right-align-the-content-inside-the-legend   this is what I am trying to do