# Aligning text in pieChart legend - How to right align the content inside the legend

Tags: jasper-reports, pie-chart

As of now my legend is displayed like this

test1 5% 
test2test2 10%

test2test2test3 85%

I am trying to display like this, with spaces and right aligned.

test1-------------------------5%
test2test2test2-----------10%
test3test3test3-----------85%

Any suggesstions appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307500/how-to-display-legend-for-pie-chart-in-columns/13309587#13309587) to create a separate panel containing your legend items. Give the panel a `GridLayout(0, 1)`; specify `JLabel.LEFT` for the left column and `JLabel.RIGHT` for the right column. A complete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2932389/how-to-right-justify-icon-in-a-jlabel/2933256#2933256).

[image]

Comment: @trashgod..thank you so much for response. I am creating a required legend panel in separate function, how do I use this new panel as the legend?

Comment: The `createLegendPanel()` method creates a panel that you can add to your layout.

Comment: I am not creating chart through code, I designed a reprot using ireport and using customizer class to modify the legend. I am overridng the method        public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart)  to modify the legend, I am not sure how to assign the legendpanel in this method.

Comment: Please update your question & tags to reflect this requirement; someone with [tag:iReport] experience may respond..