# How to use GridArrangement and BlockContainer

Tags: jfreechart

I would like to create an MxN grid of charts - similar to

```
for i in M*N:
   ax = fig.add_subplot(M, N, i + 1)
```

for matplotlib

There *appears* to be supporting classes - within the  `org.jfree.chart.block`
package.  However I have been unable to locate documentation, examples, testcases for using that arrangement/layout with a set of charts.

Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of the API is rather low-level, and mostly used internally by JFreechart. For example, `GridArrangement` may be used to [create a particular legend layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706647/how-to-draw-legend-as-a-table-with-jfreecharts/31771314#31771314), *within a chart*.

In my opinion, the easiest way to create a grid of charts, is to use a Swing `JPanel` and a [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html), and fill that grid with your charts.

```
JPanel grid = new JPanel( new GridLayout(m,n) );
for(int i=0; i<m*n; i++)
   grid.add(new ChartPanel(createChart(i)));
```

You can also use a [`CombinedPlot`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartCombinedXYPlotDemo1.htm). This allows to add as many plots as you want, either layed out side-by-side, or stacked vertically (but not on a grid, as far as I know). The good thing with this approach is that your plots will directly share a common axis, and will be aligned nicely. (But that depends on your problem: do your charts share one common axis ? Perhaps two ?)

Comment: There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513) that illustrates `CombinedDomainXYPlot`.

Comment: I am using CombinedPlot now - but yes they only have the side-by-side or stacked.  May I put the CombinedPlot inside a GridLayout?  That is my next experiment.

Answer (score 2):

To arrange the chart panels in a grid, use a `GridLayout()` on the enclosing container, as shown in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15807972/230513):

```
f.setLayout(new GridLayout(M, N));
f.add(new ChartPanel(chart1));
f.add(new ChartPanel(chart2));
…
```

[image]

Comment: Helpful - I will award to @Eric since he actually addresses the use of GridArrangement and also mentions the CombinedPlot: a bit more complete answer.

Comment: I agree; more size options are suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513).