# jfreechart pie chart fixed pie radius

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have dynamic pie set and if there are a lot of series then pie get small.

How to set fixed pie chart radius.

[image]

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117386).

Answer (score 1):

A `PiePlot` grows to fill the space available, so you'll need to give it room to grow. Some possible approaches:

1. Override [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) and use a suitable layout, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277372/230513) among other suggestions.
2. Display the legend items in an adjacent component, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309587/230513), leaving the chart alone to fill it's container.
3. Reposition the legend within the chart, as shown [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#line.422) for the default `RectangleEdge.BOTTOM`.