# Order of series in JFreeChart's StackedXYAreaChart

Tags: java, javafx, charts, jfreechart, jfreechart-fx

In the example below, *Eden* is the series at index `0`, *Survivor* at index `1` and *Old* at index `2`.

[image: Stacked Area Chart with 3 series]

It the examle, *Old* is the top-most series in the chart, while *Eden* is at the bottom.

What I would like to achieve is that *Eden* is the top-most series in the stacked chart, *Survivor* the one in the middle and *Old* on the bottom. Still, *Eden* should be the first entry in the legend and *Old* should be the last one.

I currently use the following class to create my charts:

```
public class JFreeChartFactory {
    private static String fontName = "Palatino";

    private static Color[] chartSeriesColors = {
            new Color(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.9f),
            new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.9f),
            new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.9f),
            };

    public static JFreeChart createStackedXYAreaChart(String title, String subTitle, String xAxis, String yAxis, TableXYDataset dataset) {

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createStackedXYAreaChart(
                title,
                xAxis,
                yAxis,
                dataset);

        chart.getTitle().setFont(new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, 18));

        if (subTitle != null) {
            chart.addSubtitle(new TextTitle(subTitle, new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 14)));
        }

        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setDomainPannable(true);
        plot.setRangePannable(true);
        plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setLowerMargin(0.0);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setLabelFont(new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, 14));
        plot.getDomainAxis().setTickLabelFont(new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 12));
        plot.getRangeAxis().setLabelFont(new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, 14));
        plot.getRangeAxis().setTickLabelFont(new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 12));
        chart.getLegend().setItemFont(new Font(fontName, Font.PLAIN, 14));
        chart.getLegend().setFrame(BlockBorder.NONE);
        chart.getLegend().setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < plot.getRendererCount(); i++) {
            XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer(i);
            switch (renderer.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
                case "StackedXYAreaRenderer2":
                    StackedXYAreaRenderer2 stackedRenderer = (StackedXYAreaRenderer2) renderer;
                    for (int cId = 0; cId < chartSeriesColors.length; cId++) {
                        stackedRenderer.setSeriesPaint(cId, chartSeriesColors[cId]);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return chart;
    }
}
```

Comment: As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309587/230513), you can "render a legend item in any [`Node`] you choose."