# How to center symbols in jfreechart

Tags: plot, line, jfreechart, symbols

I have a jfreechart with symbols and line drawn.  The symbols are plotted so that the top of the symbol touches the line.  I'm not sure which is in the correct position, the line or the symbol.  But, what should be changed so that the center of the symbol is on the line?

Answer (score 1):

The static method [`DefaultDrawingSupplier.createStandardSeriesShapes()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/DefaultDrawingSupplier.html#createStandardSeriesShapes%28%29) defines the standard `Shape` sequence. On [inspection](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/plot/DefaultDrawingSupplier.html#line.280), it's apparent that each `Shape` is *symmetric* about the origin. In contrast, it sounds like your `Shape` *includes* the origin as a point on its boundary. An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and [screenshot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) may clarify the matter. [`ShapeUtilities`](http://www.jfree.org/jcommon/api/org/jfree/util/ShapeUtilities.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6669529/230513), includes more examples.