# Android XYPlot set width of line, size of point and disable legend

Tags: android, jfreechart, point, legend

I'm trying to change width of line in XYPlot and size of point, any suggestion?

And another question - how i disable legend to SimpleXYSeries? Set to null cause Error.

Comment: i find only one solution to do line wider - enableShadows() :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to change width of line in `XYPlot` and size of point. Any suggestion?

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52896516/230513), you can alter the line thickness using either `setSeriesStroke()` or `setBaseStroke()` in your chosen renderer. Assuming `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`, you can change the rendered `Shape` using the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6669529/230513).

> How I disable the legend?

You can pass `false` for the `legend` parameter to your chosen `ChartFactory` method or `JFreeChart` constructor.

Comment: See also [*How to set line thickness in JFreeChart?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52890150/230513).