# How to set line thickness for multiple series in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

I create a lot of charts. In each of them I need to call

```
renderer.setSeriesStroke( i, new BasicStroke( 2.0f ) );
```

for each series. (`renderer` is `chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer()`).

I wonder if there is any way to set the thickness globally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call the renderer's <strike>`setBaseStroke()`</strike> `setDefaultStroke()` method, like they say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10932947/261156), and change the `autoPopulateSeriesStroke` flag, like they say [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=28249).

```
//renderer.setBaseStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));
renderer. setDefaultStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));
renderer.setAutoPopulateSeriesStroke(false);
```

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65612516/261156) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62727005/261156) show the new method name when [migrating](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart#migration-from-jfreechart-10x) to v1.5.

Comment: My renderer was `XYItemRenderer`, so I needed to use `((AbstractRenderer) this.renderer).setAutoPopulateSeriesStroke(false);` like in referenced link ;)

Answer (score 3):

From `Jfreechart 1.5.0` and Line Chart created with `ChartFactory.createLineChart(...)`

```
    JFreeChart lineChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(...);

    LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) lineChart.getCategoryPlot().getRenderer();
    renderer.setAutoPopulateSeriesStroke(false);
    renderer.setDefaultStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
```

Comment: is it actually different from the accepted answer? doesn't look like that

Comment: Yes, From JFreechart 1.5.0 the accepted answer won't work as the method used is now deprecated. my answer will work for those who are using the newer version.

Answer (score 1):

For Jfreechart 1.5.0:

```
XYItemRenderer renderer = lineChart.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
renderer.setDefaultStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));
((AbstractRenderer) renderer).setAutoPopulateSeriesStroke(false);
```