# How to change shape of square to dot in XYSplineRenderer Graph

Tags: jfreechart

In JFreeChart `XYSplineRenderer` Graph I need to display small dots instead of small squares to display XY coordinates. How can I change the shape of these dots? [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To center a symmetric `Shape` over a given data point, you'll want to offset the top-left corner by the radius (half the diameter). For smaller dots,

```
setSeriesShape(0, new Ellipse2D.Double(-3, -3, 6, 6));
```

See also this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6669529/230513) using `ShapeUtilities`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setBaseShape` method inherited from `AbstractRenderer`. Or you can use `setSeriesShape`

```
setBaseShape(new Ellipse2D.Float(100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f));
```