# MouseListener on jfreechart XYPlot and retrieve the correct XY point of the chart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

i have a XY plot on which i added a `ChartMouseListener` in this snippet i do this:

```
...
setContentPane(chartPanel);
plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ThisMouseListener());
class ThisMouseListener implements ChartMouseListener {

        public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event) {
             plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
             plot.setDomainCrosshairLockedOnData(true);
             plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(true);
             plot.setRangeCrosshairLockedOnData(true);
            System.out.println(plot.getDomainCrosshairValue() + " " + plot.getRangeCrosshairValue());
             plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(false);
             plot.setDomainCrosshairLockedOnData(false);
             plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(false);
             plot.setRangeCrosshairLockedOnData(false);
        }
```

EXAMPLE:

Looking on internet i found that i have to set `crossDomainVariable` to achieve what i want, which works. **But i have to be very accurate to pick the selected point.**

**What i want to do is to click a point into the XYplot area and then print the coordinated related to that point.**

Now I'm wondering if is there any other ***library function of ChartMouseListener*** of JFreechart which is more accurate.

thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You want to enlarge the area around a point in which the crosshair locks on this point? You want to know how to plot the coordinates of the selected point?

Comment: You could try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20357839/230513); as [required](http://stackexchange.com/legal), don't forget to cite the [original](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7208723/230513).