# Drawing a rotated ellipse using Ellipse.2D shape Annotation

Tags: java, jfreechart

Can any one help me to know how to draw a rotated ellipse using `Ellipse.2D` shape annotation with a given angle in `JFreeChart`?

Comment: Are you having trouble rotating or changing the shape?

Comment: I have a problem drawing the ellipse over XY PLOT CHART

Answer (score 1):

Given an `XYPlot` in  [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart), you can

- Add an `XYShapeAnnotation` to the plot, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6620017/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6802375/230513).
- Invoke `setBaseShape()` on the plot's renderer, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6669529/230513), to change the shape for a whole series.
- Override `getItemShape()` in the plot's renderer, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359200/230513), to change an individual shape.

In any case, you can rotate the `Shape` using the `createTransformedShape()` method of `AffineTransform`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594424/230513).

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation

My code is perfectly generating x,y parallel ellipse as follows:

XYShapeAnnotation unitCircle1 = new XYShapeAnnotation(
   new Ellipse2D.Double((x,y,m.h),
   new BasicStroke(0.5f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
       BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER,10.2f), Color.black);
xyPlot.addAnnotation(unitCircle1);
My problem is how to rotate this ellipse by an angle (tita)????
Thank you

Comment: I'd use `createTransformedShape()`; because code in comments is hard to read, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.