# How to start and end every series in value "0" in jFreeChart TimeSeries?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have the following chart generated by jFreeChart using JasperReports:
[image: wrong chart]

But i want it to be like this:
[image: desired chart]

How can i achieve such effect? Sorry if i can't post code, it is generated by jasper reports.

Comment: Comment for jfreechart answers if you solve it in jfreechart (java code), in jasper report its solved by implementing a [JRChartCustomizer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRChartCustomizer.html), so basically you can ignore the jasper-reports tag.... and simple link to the use of this interface

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to add data for the endpoints and override `getItemShape()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359200/230513), to display only the desired shape.