# how to make square axis with jFree chart

Tags: java, jfreechart, axis

I working with jfree chart and looking for a method that will make the axis of the plot square. basically the equivalent method for `axis square` in Matlab. 
Is there any built in method to perform this task?

thank you for your help

Comment: it is a scatter plot that constantly changing, new points are coming in every second.

Comment: See also [*Changing shape of single point in JFreeChart XYPLot*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20359200/230513), which overrides `getPreferredSize()`.

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188) or I can close as a duplicate.