# JFreeChart getSeriesStroke/Paint/Shape returns null

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

After creating a line chart by passing to JFreeChart constructor a `XYSeriesCollection` dataset, I'm trying to get either series `Stroke`/`Paint`/`Shape` as:

```
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer)chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
for (int i = 0; i < dataset.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
     renderer.getSeriesStroke(i);
     renderer.getSeriesPaint(i);
     renderer.getSeriesShape(i);
}
```

but all return null.

Why is that? How can I get the non-null objects?

Answer (score 2):

An [`XYLineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html) is an `XYItemRenderer`, which supports "rendering the visual representation of a single (x, y) item on an `XYPlot`." Although the corresponding *series* properties are `null`, the *item* properties are accessible. Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359200/230513), The following changes produce the output shown:

Code:

```
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer)chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer();
for (int i = 0; i < xyPlot.getDataset().getSeriesCount(); i++) {
     System.out.println(renderer.getItemStroke(i, 0));
     System.out.println(renderer.getItemPaint(i, 0));
     System.out.println(renderer.getItemShape(i, 0));
     System.out.println(renderer.getItemShape(i, N));
}
```

Console:

```
$ java -cp .:$JFREE_LIB/* ScatterShape
java.awt.BasicStroke@d1a007c0
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=85,b=85]
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double[x=-3.0,y=-3.0,w=6.0,h=6.0]
java.awt.geom.GeneralPath@7ef51f0f
```

[image]

Comment: That's helpful, but I still don't understand why getSeriesPaint is null - I'm adding data to the chart using series, so I would expect them to have a color.

Comment: See the abstract parent's `lookupSeriesPaint()` implementation for details.