# How can I change one point size and show label in JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

How can I change one point size/color and show label in JFreeChart? By this `ChartMouseListener`, I can get the user select witch point, and I want set the point in special style，like larger or change color, etc. Please help me how to do this.

```
       chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JFreeChart chart = arg0.getChart(); 


            if (chart == null) 
                return; 

            XYItemEntity ce = (XYItemEntity) arg0.getEntity(); 
            if (ce == null) 
                return; 
            IntervalXYDataset my = (IntervalXYDataset) ce.getDataset(); 

            int sindex = ce.getSeriesIndex(); 
            int iindex = ce.getItem(); 

            //i want make change the selectted point in here. how to do this
            System.out.println("x = " + my.getXValue(sindex, iindex)); 
            System.out.println("y = " + my.getYValue(sindex, iindex)); 
        }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Given your chosen renderer, apply a suitable label generator and override the relevant methods to return the desired shape and paint properties when the row and column match the respective series and item index recorded by your `ChartMouseListener`. In the specific case of `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`, you can

- Specify an `XYItemLabelGenerator`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14459322/230513).
- Override the `getItemShape()` method, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359200/230513),
- Override the `getItemFillPaint()` method, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9875534/230513),