# Create custom x-axis labels for line chart jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart

I created a line chart that displays time every 10 minutes on the x-axis. The data can be for a month long, so the x-axis labels are blended together (unreadable). Also, the grid lines are too close together. I need to figure out how to hide the x-axis chart labels and grid lines and create custom labels and grid lines to only show every hour (or maybe every month if I need to display the graph for a 6 month period). Currently, the x-axis labels are date time format. If 24 hour period is graphed, I need to only show the time every hour. If more than 1 month is graphed, I need to show the date.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a month's data is 6 * 24 * 30 = 4320; that's too many values to view with much precision, and 6 moths is worse. As an alternative, you can [slide](http://code.google.com/p/cori-chenxx/source/browse/aliper/trunk/aliper-core/src/test/java/com/alibaba/aliper/TranslateDemo1.java?spec=svn148&r=148) or [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844759/jfreechart-scaling-of-boxplots-with-several-categories/6849654#6849654) the data set. The default axis labels should adjust automatically. If you have problems, please post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The 10-minute ticks are way to much to display, instead you should either:

- set the NumberAxis `setAutoRange()` to `true`
- manually set the min, max and most importantly the `TickUnit`.

For dates and time go check out [DateTickUnit](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateTickUnit.html), and for numbers in general it is [NumberTickUnit](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberTickUnit.html)

If you can determine what range is displayed, it is only a matter of creating the correct `DateTickUnit`. If it for example is hours:

```
numberAxis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.HOUR, 1));
```

The gridlines you mention will be the same place as the tick marks so this should solve both problems.