# Override where jfreechart draws a point at without overriding drawItem

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have this code so far.  Right now I want to override where the point is drawn.  If the point is below 1 I want to draw the point at 1 and place an orange marker.  I have the color set up but now I want to change the Y position.  The only method I see I can override is drawItem.  But I'm not 100% sure.

```
public class XYCustomRenderer extends XYShapeRenderer {

    @Override
    public Paint getItemPaint( int series, int item ) {

        TimeSeriesCollection seriesCollection = ( TimeSeriesCollection ) getPlot().getDataset();
        //Logger.info( "" + data.getY( 0, 2 ) );

        if ( seriesCollection.getYValue( series, item ) < 1 ) {
            return Color.ORANGE;
        }

        return Color.RED;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you should be looking at how you add your data instead. How is the rest of the chart configured?

Comment: Yea I could just change how the data is added but I would prefer this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at how [`BoxAndWhiskerRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BoxAndWhiskerRenderer.html), seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844759/jfreechart-scaling-of-boxplots-with-several-categories/6849654#6849654), uses [`Outlier`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/Outlier.html). Alternatively, pin negative ordinates to some arbitrary value, e.g. 0, in your data model, and use your custom `getItemPaint()` to change the corresponding item's color.