# Save/Load jFreechart TimeSeriesCollection chart from XML

Tags: java, xml, jfreechart, dynamic-data

I'm working with this [exemple](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartDynamicDataDemo.htm) wich put rondom dynamic data into a TimeSeriesCollection chart.

[image: the data when first running the application]

[image: after a while i can not have the old data like those of the first picture]

My problem is that i can't find how to :

1- Make a track of the old data (of the **last hour**) when they pass the left boundary (because the data points move from the right to the left ) of the view area just by implementing a horizontal scroll bar.

2- Is XML a good choice to save my data into when i want to have **all** the history of the data?

```
public class DynamicDataDemo extends ApplicationFrame  {
    /** The time series data. */
    private TimeSeries series;

    /** The most recent value added. */
    private double lastValue = 100.0;


public DynamicDataDemo(final String title) {

    super(title);
    this.series = new TimeSeries("Random Data", Millisecond.class);
    final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(this.series);
    final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);

    final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

    final JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    content.add(chartPanel);
    chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
    setContentPane(content);

}


private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
    final JFreeChart result = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
        "Dynamic Data Demo", 
        "Time", 
        "Value",
        dataset, 
        true, 
        true, 
        false
    );
    final XYPlot plot = result.getXYPlot();
    ValueAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setAutoRange(true);
    axis.setFixedAutoRange(60000.0);  // 60 seconds
    axis = plot.getRangeAxis();
    axis.setRange(0.0, 200.0); 
    return result;
}


public void go() {

        final double factor = 0.90 + 0.2 * Math.random();
        this.lastValue = this.lastValue * factor;
        final Millisecond now = new Millisecond();
        System.out.println("Now = " + now.toString());
        this.series.add(new Millisecond(), this.lastValue);

}


public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final DynamicDataDemo demo = new DynamicDataDemo("Dynamic Data Demo");
    demo.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
    demo.setVisible(true);

    while(true){

        demo.go();
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    }

}



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartDynamicDataDemo.htm) uses the [default values](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html#line.169) specified in [`TimeSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html) for the maximum item age and count. You'll want to change them to suit your requirements.
2. XML is fine, but it's voluminous for high rates; plan accordingly.

See also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5048863/230513) that uses `javax.swing.Timer` to avoid blocking the event dispatch thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but for the first part hemm that's not exactly what i want to have, by checking the TimeSeries.setMaximumItemAge(long) i found that it compress the graph to keep the old data in view area, instead of adding a horizontal scroll bar. because i want to keep the graph as he was and have track the old data in the same time.

Comment: You'll want to further separate the model and view. There's a paging approach suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513).