# Candlestickchart with categories instead of timeline jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart

By default the Candlestick chart get a dataset with a timeline, is there also a dataset implementation where I can put Strings (category names) on the x-Axis instead of dates?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BoxAndWhiskerRenderer` comes to mind; there's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513) and illustration below.

[image]