# creating a chart showing mean and standard deviation in java

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, mean, standard-deviation

I'm new to Jfreechart and swing and was trying to create a single graph showing both mean (as line chart) and standard deviation (as whiskers), but failed so far.

I'm trying to make the graph look similar to that:

[image]

I've tried using graph with multiple datasets but failed to make the renderer (xyrenderer) display the whiskers for the standard deviation.

Is there a better way to do this?
perhaps some other free package?

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for the [`XYBoxAndWhiskerRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYBoxAndWhiskerRenderer.html), which uses a `BoxAndWhiskerXYDataset`; the related `BoxAndWhiskerRenderer` is illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.
However, we are looking for a way of getting just the whiskers without the boxplots. in the class metnioned here they are integrated, is there a way to seperate them?
In addition, I'm looking for a way to add an additional layer to the whiskers, that is a continuous line, representing average.
How can this be done?

Comment: You might want to look at `XYErrorRenderer` and also review the `Statistical Charts` in the JWS demo.