# Jfreechart:displaying multiple charts

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I am new to java and JFreecharts and I am using Jfreechart to create many charts(barcharts and piecharts). I display the charts as and when it is created. But all the charts which are generated gets stacked upon the other and the last chart is on the top. If i close the last one all the charts gets closed. I want to know if it is possible to have only one frame and all the charts can be navigated using a 'next' and 'previous'button. If anyone has experience in this, please share.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Has less to do with JFreeChart, more with Swing. With JTabbedPane the user could elect immediately the pie chart as there is a tab "Pie." With previous+next you can have a panel that on button click sets the next/previous chart into the panel.

Comment: @JoopEggen: what i have is 6 functions, which calculate 6 different parameter and each one creates a Jfreechart(barchart, piechart, xylinechart). Each time I construct a panel that displays the specified jfreechart. Then, I set the size of the panel and then call setContentPane(panel) and sets the frame to visible.

Answer (score 3):

The following is more to get you started. Better use a GUI editor like that of the NetBeans IDE.
Mind the following is typed, without seeing a compiler.

Fields:

```
private static final int CHARTS = 6;
private int currentChartNo = 0;
private JButton previousButton = new JButton("<");
private JButton nextButton = new JButton(">");
private JPanel currentChartPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel[] chartPanels = new JPanel[CHARTS];
```

Initialisation in the frame:

```
// getContentPane(), having per default a BorderLayout.
add(currentChartPanel , BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(previousButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
add(nextButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

previousButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (currentChartNo > 0) {
            getContentPane().remove(currentChartPanel);
            --currentChartNo;
            currentChartPanel = chartPanels[currentChartNo];
            getContentPane().add(currentChartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            repaint(100L);
        }
    }
});
```

It can be made nicer, with an extra chart containing panel.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to multiple instances of `ChartPanel`, you can create a series of datasets and update a single panel, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513).

[image]