# Jfree chart - XYLine chart plot huge data

Tags: jfreechart

I have a requirement to plot multiple xyline chart each with huge dataset(per second data for 7 days).
The issue is that the system consume huge memory.

Is there any way to overcome this memory issue?Can i start plotting the graph and add the data dynamically during the plotting?.

Note:This is for a webapplication using spring and the data is fetched from database.

Comment: Use a paging approach, illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You shold use a [`SamplingXYLineRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/SamplingXYLineRenderer.html)

From the documentation:

> The renderer doesn't necessarily plot every data item - instead, it
>   tries to plot only those data items that make a difference to the
>   visual output (the other data items are skipped). This renderer is
>   designed for use with the XYPlot class.