# Load many data to a Jtable efficient

Tags: java, performance, swing, file-io, jtable

I have a file and i read data from this and put them in a `jTable`. The problem is that when the file has many data (e.g 300.000 rows), my application needs a lot of memory (350MB). Is there any efficient way in order to load many rows in a `JTable`?

I created a `Default Model` and a Jtable like that:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(array, colNames);
JTable data_table = new JTable();
data_table.setModel(model);
```

The array 'array' contains the data and the array 'colNames' the names of the Columns.

Comment: If you're loading files that large into tables, it's probably inevitable that you consume a lot of memory. Is it necessary to keep all that data in memory at once? How is the data being loaded from file?

Comment: I want to make search e.g for a record in the JTable. If data are not in memory how can i do this?

Comment: There are some alternatives available to you, but the fastest way to access that data is through volatile memory. It might be unavoidable that your application leans towards larger memory footprints. How are you loading the data in from the file?

Comment: i open the file i read the first line, split it and i store it in the two dimensional array 'array'

Comment: e.g 300.000 rows is beyond/overloading human possibility, loading can take more that 2-3minutes, sorting/filtering is about how to spent free time, use paginations logics ....

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reduce the memory consuption of your program.
You could use `java.nio.channels.FileChannel` and map parts of the file to your main memory.

But you would have to reload/change current mapping, depending on your view.
Take a look at the javadoc of the [`map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) method.

---

I don' know what exactly your file is, but if you just use it as a simplistic replacement for an actual database. You're better off with using a real one.

Answer (score 3):

Use an embedded database, and store only the record ID in the model and then only if you need to filter/sort rows.

Answer (score 3):

Absent enough information to offer a particular solution, you may be able to identify a reasonable partition function for your data's primary key, e.g. a `String` prefix or a `Date` range. Use an adjacent control to update the `TableModel` based on the selection. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513), buttons are used to change a chart's data model. To minimize latency, Use `SwingWorker`. Aside from the memory problem, you may want to [filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) the table or load the file into an in-memory database such as [H2 Database](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/h2/info).

Comment: I like the idea about identifying a function for the primary key. If the key had information encoded. One could do simple operations with out the actual data and only load if when it is demanded.