# How to determine the amount of data displayed on chartpanel?

Tags: java, jfreechart

How to determine the amount of data displayed (candles) of the dataset (DefaultOHLCDataset) to a visible chart does not exceed a certain number. I have an extensive dataset, which displays some data. To date, the amount of data displayed was limited by zoom state, but instead I would like to set the number of displayed data for each zoom levels, eg for zoom = 0= 45 data, for zoom = 1= 20 data.

Answer (score 1):

You might see if you can usefully adapt the paging approach seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513) for `BoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset`.

Comment: It is nice solution, but, when I add some annotations to plot, it gets too difficult, when dataset has not all of data; in example triangle or ellipse.

Comment: Yes, the example is simplistic in terms of object decomposition; in order to store the annotation data in the model, you might look at extending `DefaultOHLCDataset` or implementing the required interfaces.