# How to customize legend of a BoxAndWhisker plot

Tags: java, user-interface, jfreechart

I've created a [`BoxAndWhiskerRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BoxAndWhiskerRenderer.html) plot using `JFreeChart` and it seems that it is automatically creating a sort of legend (see attached picutre).

[image]

Is there a way to remove the outside border of this legend and customize the font  of the labels in the legend items?

Here is an example of my code:

```
//Get the desired BoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset from a LinkedHashMap
BoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset dataset = values.get(b);

//Create X axis
CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
xAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);

//Create Y axis
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(b.getLabel());
yAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
yAxis.setTickLabelFont(FDFont.getFont(12f));
yAxis.setLabelFont(FDFont.getFont());
yAxis.setLabelPaint(FDPalette.secondaryText);
yAxis.setTickLabelPaint(FDPalette.secondaryText);
yAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);

//Create renderer
BoxAndWhiskerRenderer renderer = new BoxAndWhiskerRenderer();
int count = 0;
for(Map.Entry<Integer,Color> map : clusterColor.entrySet()){
    //Set color for the series (I have a previously created map which links colors and series)
    renderer.setSeriesPaint(count,map.getValue());
    count++;
}
renderer.setFillBox(true);
renderer.setToolTipGenerator(new BoxAndWhiskerToolTipGenerator());
CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);

JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(plot);
chart.setBackgroundPaint(white);
chart.setBorderVisible(false);

ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(300, 270));
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6844759/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6844759/230513), the simplest [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html) constructor adds a legend by default. The code for doing so is seen [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#line.422); simply substitute your desired frame, color and position.

Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513), the following changes produce the chart shown below:

```
private void createChartPanel() {
    …
    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("BoxAndWhiskerDemo", plot);
    LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
    legend.setFrame(new LineBorder(Color.white, new BasicStroke(1.0f),
        new RectangleInsets(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)));
    legend.setItemFont(legend.getItemFont().deriveFont(16f));
    chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
}
```

[image]

Compare to this default legend:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I'm having problems in testing the examples you posted. E.g. If I try with `LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();`, it says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Legend to LegendTitle` and I'm not allowed to cast `Legend` to `LegendTitle`. I edited my previous post including an example of my code.

Comment: In what way are you _not allowed to cast_? Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach to calling `getLegend()`; you an skip the custom fonts & colors for this.

Comment: If I write `LegendTitle legend = (LegendTitle)chart.getLegend();` it throws a compilation error: `Cannot cast from Legend to LegendTitle`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you adding other legends? Without your [mcve] I can only guess.

Comment: My Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example is in the post above. Probably, the example cannot be compiled because of the `BoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset` and the color of the series, but I think they don't affect my problem. I'm not adding any legend (it is automatically added) nor doing anything but what is in the code above.

Comment: I've illustrated a complete example above.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was that my version of JFreeChart was not updated to the latest release. Now your code perfectly works.