# BoxandWhisper not plotting the whisker for some values

Tags: java, charts, rendering, jfreechart

Box and whisper not plotting the lines for some values
Out of 5 lines I see only one sometimes. Please tell me the scenario where I get the far or low triangles

```
  DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset();
    List<Double> values = new ArrayList();
    values.add(14);
    values.add(14);
    values.add(14);
    values.add(14);
    dataset.add(values, "","");
    BoxAndWhiskerRenderer r = new BoxAndWhiskerRenderer();
    CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, new CategoryAxis("x"),
            new NumberAxis("y"), r);
    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(plot);
```

Mean is same as q1 so it's not coming

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that includes actual data, rather than pictures of data; these [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20BoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset) may offer guidance.

Comment: Try this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513) in particular.