# How can I order columns in a box chart in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, sorting, graph, charts, jfreechart

I have a box chart with multiple boxes in rows and columns. The ordering of the boxes is wrong. Each row (color) is labeled by an enum constant of type `Multiple`, and each column (group) is labeled by an enum constant of type `Type`. (The real names of the types are different; This is simplified.)

The code to generate the chart is like this, but this has many things omitted because I think that they are not important:

```java
var results; // results are predefined
var dataset = new DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset();

for (Type type : results.keySet()) { // type is an enum constant
    var innerResults = results.get(type);
    for (Multiple multiple : innerResults.keySet()) { // multiple is an enum constant
        List<Double> values; // calculate values here
        dataset.add(values, multiple, type);
} }

var chart = ChartFactory.createBoxAndWhiskerChart(
    "",
    "type",
    "",
    dataset,
    true
);
```

This is the resulting chart:

[image: box chart with wrongly ordered columns]

The order of the multiples is supposed to be ascending (“0.25”, “0.5”, …). The order of the types is supposed to be “hard MW”, “soft MW”, “multiple-overlay MW”. That is how they are declared in the source code, so that is how they are ordered according to `compareTo`. I didn't find that JFreeChart would have a documented ordering for rows and columns, but that is how I expect it.

Why are the boxes in this order and not the expected one? How can I force JFreeChart to sort the rows and columns how I expect it? I have no idea what causes this; I have a very similar chart, but the order there is correct.

Comment: Do your row and column keys implement `Comparable` as intended?

Comment: Related examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset).

Comment: @trashgod Yes, enums automatically implement `Comparable`, and their order is how they are declared in the source code. That's why I mentioned it in the question. I didn't override the comparing.

Comment: I [see](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo(E)): "The natural order implemented by this method is the order in which the constants are declared." This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849654/230513) appears to be ordered as expected according to `String name`.

Comment: As the `keySet()` of a `Map` is generally unordered, you may need to use a `SortedSet` to get the desired behavior.

Comment: @trashgod That is a good point. I expected that the order of insertion of the data would not matter, but it matters. I didn't use a SortedSet; I sorted the values in a stream, like `…keySet().stream().sorted().toList()`. I prefer that because the method calls go just to the right.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! I've summarized the comments below. Please don't hesitate to correct any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing our colloquy, your [dataset](https://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset.html) row and column keys are held by an [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html), which implements `Comparable`. In [particular](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo(E)), "The natural order implemented by this method is the order in which the constants are declared." However, because the values come from a `keySet()` held by the enum, they are generally unordered. While it may be possible to substitute a `SortedSet`, you have chosen to sort each set explicitly:

```
keySet().stream().sorted().toList()
```